# Quarkus PanacheMongoEntity - Is there no automatic encoding/decoding of Enum?

Tags: mongodb, bson, quarkus

This is my Entity "WebhookType":

```
public class WebhookType extends PanacheMongoEntity {

    public ObjectId id;
    public String type;
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public String image;
    public List<WebhookTypeParameter> webhookTypeParameters = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Which is having a list of "WebhookTypeParameters":

```
public class WebhookTypeParameter {

    public Enum<ParameterType> parameterType;
    public String parameterName;
    public String parameterExample;

    public WebhookTypeParameter(){
    }

    public Enum<ParameterType> getParameterType() {
        return parameterType;
    }

    public void setParameterType(Enum<ParameterType> parameterType) {
        this.parameterType = parameterType;
    }

    public String getParameterName() {
        return parameterName;
    }

    public void setParameterName(String parameterName) {
        this.parameterName = parameterName;
    }

    public String getParameterExample() {
        return parameterExample;
    }

    public void setParameterExample(String parameterExample) {
        this.parameterExample = parameterExample;
    }

    public WebhookTypeParameter(String parameterName, Enum<ParameterType>parameterType, String parameterExample){
        this.setParameterName(parameterName);
        this.setParameterType(parameterType);
        this.setParameterExample(parameterExample);
    }
}
```

Which are having a field "parameterType" of Type Enum:

```
public enum ParameterType  {
    STRING, DOUBLE;
}
```

Now when trying to persist my entity like this:

```
        WebhookType webhookType = new WebhookType();
        webhookType.type = "XYZ";
        webhookType.name = "XYZ";
        webhookType.image = "image url";
        webhookType.description = ("Lorem Ipsum");
        webhookType.webhookTypeParameters.add(new WebhookTypeParameter("title", ParameterType.STRING, "titel xy"));
        webhookType.webhookTypeParameters.add(new WebhookTypeParameter("name", ParameterType.STRING, "foobar"));
        webhookType.persist();
```

I get this in my log:

```
2020-09-19 14:01:07,587 ERROR [io.qua.application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: An exception occurred when encoding using the AutomaticPojoCodec.
Encoding a WebhookType: 'WebhookType<null>' failed with the following exception:

Failed to encode 'WebhookType'. Encoding 'webhookTypeParameters' errored with: An exception occurred when encoding using the AutomaticPojoCodec.
Encoding a WebhookTypeParameter: 'x.x.x.WebhookTypeParameter@474d3e58' failed with the following exception:

Failed to encode 'WebhookTypeParameter'. Encoding 'parameterType' errored with: Can't find a codec for class x.x.x.ParameterType.

A custom Codec or PojoCodec may need to be explicitly configured and registered to handle this type.
```

So my question is what's wrong with my enum and why is it not automatically encoded?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Enum` generic type that encapsulate your ` ParameterType` enum ? Can you update your question with it's code ?

Comment: What do you mean with Enum generic type?

Comment: This: `public Enum<ParameterType> parameterType;`. You have a generic class Enum that is not part of the Java SDK.
What is the purpose of this class? Why don't you directly use the `ParameterType`enum ?

Comment: You mean storing a String in class WebhookTypeParameter instead of the Enum?

Comment: No, I means using your enum directly: `public ParameterType parameterType;`
I have no idea where your `Enum`type is comming, can you show us your import and explaining what is it doing ?